# MX 19 won't see an NTFS filesystem

Tags: partition, ntfs, mx-linux

I am running a brand-new install of MX 19.4 Patito Feo on one hard drive and have a second drive plugged in for file storage.  The problem is that MX 19 refuses to mount the single `ntfs` partition on this secondary drive.  I have tried it using the fstab file, the mount command in the terminal, and the file manager's GUI, but without success.  The drive may be defective, but I seriously doubt it.  I have tried accessing the data partition using an older MX 18.3 system, and it worked fine.

I should explain here that, upon booting into MX, the computer refuses to see the drive at all.  I have tried adding the partition to the `/etc/fstab` file, but there is no visible change in the system's behavior.  Entering this line into the terminal directly after a reboot:

```
sudo mount /dev/[PARTITION] /media/[MOUNT-POINT]
```

...yields this result:

```
mount: /media/[MOUNT-POINT]: special device /dev/[PARTITION] does not exist.
```

This holds true whether the partition is in the `fstab` file or not.  The file manager does not see the partition, either.  But when I open GParted, a prompt immediately appears asking me to enter the administrative password in order to mount the drive. (Entering the password yields no results.) The partition also appears in the file manager, and the `mount` command yields a different error:

```
ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Device or resource busy
```

Please note that this second error ONLY appears after I open GParted, and it occurs even if I choose not to enter the password in the prompt.

I also tried creating another smaller `ntfs` partition on the same drive, but MX treated it just like the other.

**System information:**

- Main OS: MX 19.4 Patito Feo (64-bit)
- Other OS: MX 18.3 Continuum (32-bit)
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz
- Motherboard: ASUSTeK P5KPL-CM
- Problem hard drive: WDC WD5003ABYX-18WERA0
- Other hard drive: WDC WD2500AAKX-753CA0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you would like any further details, let me know, and I will provide them.

Comment: Only add the drive to `/etc/fstab` once you have it "working". Use `sudo lsblk -l` to explore. You cannot edit a disk with `gparted` if ANY of the disk's partitions is mounted. Sometimes Windows "Fast Boot" shutdown causes problems. Read `man ntfsfix` or take the drive back to Windows and run `chkdsk`.

Comment: I don't have a Windows system.  I created this `ntfs` system using Linux for Linux storage.  Is there a better option than `ntfs` for a system only intended for storage?  I only used `ntfs` because I know that it _is_ used for storage at times.

Comment: `ext4`, a journaling filesystem, is a better choice, but there are many better choices than Winows-derived NTFS

Comment: Before reformatting your drive, figure out what is wrong. Use `sudo fdisk -l;sudo  journalctl -b 0 /dev/sd`

Comment: The `journalctl` command yielded `No journal files were found`.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved for me by installing `ntfs-3g`.

`sudo apt install ntfs-3g`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate why you think the `ntfs-3g` package is missing on the OP's installation (and in particular, why the mount attempt would yield a "device or resource busy" answer in that case).